# How do I import updates to unique data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a reasonably large MySQL database that is an import of CSV values from a public data repository.  It has come to my attention lately that they occasionally update (ie. correct) data, usually from records published within the last few months.  And, when I update my data, I only pull the last few months (not the entire database again).

I'm trying to figure out a way to import the recent data on a regular basis where it will OVERWRITE the current data with the new data if it conflicts.  I have previously been doing this using the IGNORE command, to avoid conflicts, but that obviously keeps the original values.

I'd also prefer not to simply overwrite the entire database each month as it is a large file.  So importing is a pain at over a gig of data.

So, is there a command like IGNORE that I can use that will have the opposite effect? One that will replace all columns that match unique keys (and thus cause a conflict) with the data from the NEWER import. Or a similar strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite for `INSERT IGNORE` is `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Refer to the chapter 14.2.5.3 of MySQL reference for further details.

Comment: Thank you, I looked everywhere for that but could not track it down.  I will confirm and accept your answer afterwards.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you aware of any way to specify a certain key value to trigger the update?  In other words, if sales are different, Update, otherwise ignore.

Comment: If any defined index of `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` type cause the duplication then defined update behaviour will be implied.

Answer (score 0):

Some rows are new and need `INSERTing`?  And some rows match on some `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key, so they need `UPDATEing`?  Or left alone if nothing changed?

If yes, the IODKU seems like the perfect command -- it will *either* `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.  (And if nothing changes in the `UPDATE` path, then it is 'cheap'.)

Do you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` key?  (I hope not; that complicates things.)

If there is a performance problem, then load the CSV into a temp table, then use a minor variant on the 2 SQL statements given [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization).